# Select statement with containing a certain criteria

Tags: sql

I have a column that contain these value from a table.

```
Colum1: dhd-29229 Table: Test
        dhd-29199
        dhd-00011
```

My goal is to write a select sql statement that will return the following value: All numeric value and not take into account dhd-

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1):

Use `like`:

```
where column1 like '%29229'
```

Comment: what is the value is 0001, I'm trying to come up with a solution that use a substring and a charIndex

Comment: @YvesGuyon . . . And I'm trying to answer the question you actually asked.  If you have another question, you should ask *another* question.  `like` is the best approach for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly XXX-29199 in this format, you've to use :

```
where column1 like '___-29229'
```

If you want just the 29229, you can use : `where column1 like '%29229'` but in this case the query **will return all values that ends with "29229"**. you can think to controle the length.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Answer (score 0):

in T-SQL (sql server):
select substring(colum1, charindex('-',colum1)+1,5) as sub_string from test

Answer (score 0):

If you want a strict 'numbers only' that does not reply upon format or inconsistencies... try writing a UDF :

```
Create FUNCTION [test].[numOnly]
(@text nvarchar (max))
RETURNS nvarchar (max)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE 
    @char nvarchar(1),
    @i_idx int,
    @temp int,
    @out nvarchar(max)

    While len(@text) > 0
    Begin
        Set @char = left(@text,1)
            if ascii(@char) between 49 and 57
                set @out = isnull(@out,'') + @char

            Set @text = RIGHT(@text,len(@text)-1)
    End

    Return @out
END
```

Use it thus ...

```
select  [test].[numOnly]('44--(*)"*()£hllk564kkj3') as 'lala'
```

> Result : 445643